# How to add page not found route with feature modules

Tags: angular, module, routes

We have Angular application modules where each application is responsible to defining their routes.  This all works fine except we would also like a page not found route.

```
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
```

What is the best practice for adding this route last.  In other words each application module would not define it, is there a way to add it after all feature modules have loaded their routes?

My app-module-router.ts looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', children: [

  { path: '', redirectTo: '/pleaseSelect', pathMatch: 'full' },  
  { path: 'restricted', component: AuthorityRestrictedComponent,
     data: { title : 'Restricted'},  canActivate: [AuthorityChecker] },
  { path: 'pleaseSelect', component: PleaseSelectComponent,
     data: { title : 'Please Select'},  canActivate: [AuthorityChecker] },
  { path: 'notAuthorized', component: NotAuthorizedComponent,
    data: { title : 'Not Authorized'},  canActivate: [AuthorityChecker] }
  ], resolve: {translation: BaseTranslationResolve }}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
             { enableTracing: false } 
      )],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

A typical application routing looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', children: [


    { path: 'orderSearch', component: OrderSearchComponent,
      data: { title : 'Order Search'}, canActivate: [AuthorityChecker], 
      resolve: {translation: OrderBundleResolve }},
    { path: 'orderEdit/:orderID', component: OrderEditComponent,
      data: { title : 'Order Edit'}, canActivate: [AuthorityChecker], 
      canDeactivate: [ConfirmLooseChanges],
      resolve: {translation: OrderBundleResolve }},
    { path: 'orderAdd', component: OrderAddComponent,
      data: { title : 'Order Add'}, canActivate: [AuthorityChecker], 
      canDeactivate: [ConfirmLooseChanges],
      resolve: {translation: OrderBundleResolve }},
  ], resolve: {translation: BaseTranslationResolve }}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
         { enableTracing: false } 
  )],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class OrderRoutingModule {
}
```

It all works fine without the PageNotFoundComponent.  If I add it to the end of the app-module-router.ts, none of the application routes work anymore.  They all result in page not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find the solution with the back and forth above (thanks Narm).  It is now obvious and and a little embarrassing but here goes.  The order matters!  Below I have two feature modules: OrderModule and PurchasingModule.  They have their own routes defined for their apps.  The AppRoutingModule has all the generic routes and NOW has the ** PageNotFoundComponent.  All I did was move it last after the apps modules.  :-)

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    OrderModule,
    PurchasingModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need only add it in your root router module. If you're using an Angular Cli project that would be your `app-routing.module.ts`

I wouldn't worry about the "waiting until all feature modules have loaded their routes", because during Angulars compilation phase all modules are merged into one factory.

**Update:**
From the code you provided here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-tdowgu) I created with similar router config to yours.

Comment: Unfortunately when I do this none of my routes in my application routes work.  I get the page not found component for any app route.

Comment: Will you share your router-module code then? Make sure your wildcard route is the very last route in your module.

Comment: Yes, I edited the question and added my app-routing-module routes and a typical application.  When I add the wildcard route to the end of app-routing-module, it masks all the application routes.

Comment: Check the answer with updated Stack. I put a working demo, I can't reproduce your issue. If that doesn't help, fork the StackBlitz and see if you can reproduce with [mcve]

Comment: Actually your slack example is not representative of what I am doing (you had a single route file and I have multiple) but I was able to figure out what the problem was.  I will post an answer.  It actually is pretty obvious once my light build went on.